# how to convert the white pixels in a black and white image into a specific shape?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

i am working on a project to track the object using thermal sensors. the output of the sensor will be temperature reading which i converted into black and white image where white pixels portraits the object. but due to some noises the shape obtained is irregular and i would like to reshape the image into circular shape as shown in figure 2. Is there any method through which I can convert the white pixels of the figure 1 into specific shape (preferably circle) as shown in figure 2 using python. Any help is truly appreciated.

what i have:

[image: 1]

what i want:

[image: 2]

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Do you want to erase your shape and draw an arbitrary ellipse into the image? Or should the ellipse be related to the shape in some way? Please [edit] your post to describe more precisely what properties this ellipse should have.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html)? If not please add some more information to your question and a code example that shows where you got stuck! Read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you don't **need** it to be an ellipse, you can use the convex hull of your shape, as shown below :
[image: convex hull]

This can be done easily with [scikit image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_convex_hull.html) :

```
from skimage.morphology import convex_hull_image
from skimage import data, img_as_float
from skimage.util import invert

# The original image is inverted as the object must be white.
image = invert(data.horse())

chull = convex_hull_image(image)
```